# Animating progress bars with CSS

Tags: html, css, jquery-animate

So, I have a few different progress bars on this page - http://kaye.at/play/goals

Here's my HTML & CSS:

```
<div class="meter"><span style="width: 100%;"></span></div>


.meter { 
height: 5px;
position: relative;
background: #f3efe6;
z-index: 0;
margin-top: -5px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.meter > span {
z-index: 50;
display: block;
height: 100%;
background-color: #e4c465;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

I want to simply animate the progress bar so that it slowly goes up from 0% to whatever percentage it's at, rather than just appearing there, but I'd like to do it in the simplest way possible. What's my best option and is it possible with the current code I'm using?

Comment: Use `animation` with `@keyframes` (for example per 10% for 10 seconds) and use `:after` so you can draw progress icons in there (like `#` or `•`).

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, can you give me a HTML/CSS example? I'm a bit of an amateur, just work on my own personal stuff.

Comment: Ok, I've figured it out! Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only way I can think to animate to your width set inline is to add another `span`, so the HTML ends up as:

```
<div class="meter">
    <span style="width:80%;"><span class="progress"></span></span>
</div>
```

That extra span is needed, as we have no way (using just CSS) of checking what the inline style wants the width to be and so animating to it. And unfortunately we can't animate to `auto`.

The CSS (you'll need to add the necessary prefixes):

```
.meter { 
    height: 5px;
    position: relative;
    background: #f3efe6;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.meter span {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}

.progress {
    background-color: #e4c465;
    animation: progressBar 3s ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode:both; 
}

@keyframes progressBar {
  0% { width: 0; }
  100% { width: 100%; }
}
```

You can see this in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/Bq3Fm/). Browsers that don't support CSS animations will just get the bar in its final state.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I ended up doing. (:

Comment: No worries - it's a very nice looking site :)

Answer (score 8):

I developed a progress bar so that it's so light and neat right now and you have percentage value too, I applied CSS transition when the percentage changes from 100% to 7%, just click on the `Change` button to see how it works. Change `transition: width 3s ease;` from 3s to whatever fits your need for slower or faster transition.

```js
function change(){
    var selectedValue = document.querySelector("#progress-value").value;
    document.querySelector(".progress-bar-striped > div").textContent = selectedValue + "%";
    document.querySelector(".progress-bar-striped > div").style.width = selectedValue + "%";
   }
```

```css
.progress-bar-striped {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   }
   .progress-bar-striped > div {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -webkit-transition: width 3s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 3s ease;
    -o-transition: width 3s ease;
    transition: width 3s ease;
    animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
    background-color: #288ade;
   }
   .progress-bar-striped p{
    margin: 0;
   }
   
   @keyframes progress-bar-stripes {

    0% {
     background-position: 40px 0;
    }
    100% {
     background-position: 0 0;
    }
   }
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar-striped">
   <div style="width: 100%;"><b><p>100%</p></b></div>
  </div>
  <div>
   <input id="progress-value" type="number" placeholder="Enter desired percentage" min="0" max="100" value="7" />
   <input type="button" value="Change" onclick="change()"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is the better answer. The accepted one will only animate the progress bar if the width is increasing. If you have a situation where a user can go back, you need to animate both directions, which is easily done with `transition: width 2s ease` and 2 divs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a single div proposal on pure css

```css
#progressBar {
    height: 3px;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index:2;
    background: #DDDDDD;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: progressBar 1.5s ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-fill-mode:both;
    bottom:0;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    left:0;
}


@keyframes progressBar {
    0% { left:0;width: 0; }
    50% { left:0;width: 100%; }
    100% {left:100%;width: 0}
}
```